# Let $f$ be an entire function. Then choose the correct options from below

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I know that $f$ is entire. So 4 is correct option. 3 is false option (Liouville theorem) How to give conclusion in 1,2. Please give some hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is analytic, then it is a $C^\infty$ function if we see it as a function from $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R^2$. So, its first component (which is $u$) is also a $C^\infty$ function. Therefore, the first option is true and the second one is false.